# Why do multiple lines in python need print()?

Tags: python

```
multiline = "Life is too short\nYou need python."
 
multiline #1
#'Life is too short\nYou need python.'

print(multiline) #2
#Life is too short
#You need python.
```

I don't know why the result of #1 can't show the same result of #2.

Comment: the first variant just shows you how it is stored, that includes the `\n`. When using `print()` that `\n` actually gets converted to a newline character.

Comment: To print something you always need `print`. Your REPL might show the representation of a variable, but that won't happen when you run the script.

Answer (score 7):

#1 is just showing you the result of `repr(multiline)`, a non-ambiguous representation of the contents of `multiline`.

#2 is actually writing each character of `multiline` to standard output, with each character being shown in a terminal-dependent fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Result one shows what you have input that is it will display it in the same format as you have input

Whereas the second one will give the output when the program is run